# How do I make a recursive macro to factorize this code?

Tags: rust, macros

I tried to make a macro that factorizes some code.

```
trait Animal {
    fn crie(&self) -> String;
    fn crie_plusieurs_fois(&self, n: isize) -> String {
        let mut res = "".to_string();
        if n > 0 {res = self.crie() + " " + &*res + &*self.crie_plusieurs_fois(n - 1) }
        res
    }
}

struct Chien {}
struct Chat {}

impl Animal for Chien {
    fn crie(&self) -> String {
        "wouaf".to_string()
    }
}


impl Animal for Chat {
    fn crie(&self) -> String {
        "miaou".to_string()
    }
}
```

I have this and I want to create this:

```
enum Animals{
    CHIEN(Chien),
    CHAT(Chat)
}

impl Animal for Animals{
    fn crie(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Animals::CHIEN(c) => c.crie(),
            Animals::CHAT(c) => c.crie(),
        }
    }
}
```

with these recursive macros:

```
macro_rules! impl_trait_for_enum{
    (
        $nom_trait: ident;

        $nom_enum: ident => $($nom_fonction:ident($($nom_var:ident : $type_var:ty),*) $(-> $type_retour:ty)?),+ ;

        $($identifiant : ident => $structure : ident),+
    ) => {

        enum $nom_enum{
            $($identifiant($structure)),+
        }

        impl $nom_trait for $nom_enum {
           impl_trait_function!($nom_enum; $($identifiant),+; $($nom_fonction ($($nom_var : $type_var),*) $(-> $type_retour)?),*);
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! impl_trait_function{
    (
        $nom_enum: ident;

        $($identifiant: ident ),*;

        $nom_fonction: ident($($nom_var:ident : $type_var:ty),*) $(-> $type_retour:ty)?,

        $($autre_nom_fonction: ident($($autre_nom_var:ident : $ autre_type_var:ty),*) $(-> $autre_type_retour:ty)?),*
    )=> {
        fn $nom_fonction(&self$(,$nom_var: $type_var),* ) $(-> $type_retour)? {
            match self {
                impl_multiple_pattern!($nom_enum;$nom_fonction($($nom_var),*); $($identifiant),*);
            }
        }
        impl_trait_function!($nom_enum; $($identifiant),+;
                            $($autre_nom_fonction ($($autre_nom_var : $ autre_type_var),*) $(-> $autre_type_retour)?),*);
    };
    ($nom_enum: ident; $($identifiant: ident),+;) => {}
}

macro_rules! impl_multiple_pattern {
    (
        $nom_enum: ident;

        $nom_fonction: ident($($nom_var: ident),*);

        $identifiant: ident,

        $($autre_identifiant: ident),*

    )=>{
        $nom_enum::$identifiant(s) => s.$nom_fonction($(nom_var: ident)*),
        impl_multiple_pattern($nom_enum; $nom_fonction($($nom_var)*); $rest);
    };

    (
        $nom_enum: ident;

        $nom_fonction: ident($($nom_var: ident)*);
    ) => {}


}
```

and this call

```
impl_trait_for_enum!(  Animals; Animal => crie() -> String, crie_plusieur_fois(n: isize) -> String;
                        Dog => Chien,
                        Cat => Chat
                       );
```

I have this error:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|`, found `;`
   --> src/main.rs:101:98
    |
101 |                   impl_multiple_pattern!($nom_enum;$nom_fonction($($nom_var),*); $($identifiant),*);
    |                                                                                                    ^ expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|`
...
134 | / impl_trait_for_enum!(
135 | |             Animal; Animals => crie() -> String, crie_plusieurs_fois(n: isize) -> String;
136 | |             Dog => Chien,
137 | |             Cat => Chat
138 | |         );
    | |__________- in this macro invocation
    |
    = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: unexpected end of macro invocation
   --> src/main.rs:105:115
    |
89  | macro_rules! impl_trait_function{
    | -------------------------------- when calling this macro
...
105 |                             $($autre_nom_fonction ($($autre_nom_var : $ autre_type_var),*) $(-> $autre_type_retour)?),*);
    |                                                                                                                   ^ missing tokens in macro arguments
```

The goal is to have an object collection with differents objects which implement the same trait whitout use something like this 'Vec< dyn Trait>' because sometimes I have to make different thing depending of the object .

My solution with an enum and match pattern is working good but I am writing a lot of similar pieces of code. It's what I'm trying to avoid whith these macros.

---

I am not allowed to call a macro in match pattern like this:

```
match self {
                impl_multiple_pattern!($nom_enum;$nom_fonction($($nom_var),*); $($identifiant),*);
            }
```

Is my idea impossible to do with a macro?

Comment: Copying that code into a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) does not yield the same compiler messages. Please consider double-checking that code and perhaps including a link to the playground where this can be reproduced. Do not forget to format your code as well. See also the Rust-specific tips for asking a good question in the tag's [information page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info).